Angular getCurrentUser different roles with different models
I have a logic issue and I’m not sure how to proceed. I have an auth method that sends email and password, and my API responds with a JWT token. Then, I need a getCurrentUser method, but I have multiple roles, each with its own model—for example, I have admin, moderator, and user, and each has its own model. How should I approach this?
I’ve thought about having 3 methods: LoadCurrentUser, LoadCurrentModo, and LoadCurrentAdmin, each receiving its own model. I’m not sure if it’s a good approach and how I could determine which method to call after the user has authenticated. Then, I asked ChatGPT if it has any idea.
export type UserType = Admin | Modo | User;

getCurrentUser(): Observable<UserType> {
  return this.http.get<UserType>(`/api/user/current`).pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      switch (data.role) {
        case 'admin':
          return data as Admin;
        case 'modo':
          return data as Modo;
        default:
          return data as User;
      }
    })
  );
}


My current method with Ngrx Signal Store :
      getCurrentUser: rxMethod<void>(
        pipe(
          tap(() => patchState(store, { isLoading: true })),
          concatMap((input) => {
            return infra.loadCurrentUser().pipe(
              tapResponse({
                next: (user) => {
                  patchState(store, {
                    isLoading: false,
                    user: user,
                  });
                },
                error: () => {
                  patchState(store, { isLoading: false });
                },
              })
            );
          })
        )
      ),

Do you have an idea?

Do the models extend from each other? Or are they completely separate?

They extend from the User model, which includes fields such as First Name, Last Name, and Email.

As Admin and Modo extend from User, your getCurrentUser() function should return an Observable of type User.
getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get<User>(`/api/user/current`);
}

Now you can offer functions to check if a user is an admin or modo, using the is keyword:
isAdminUser(user: User): user is Admin {
  return 'role' in user && user.role === 'admin';
}

isModoUser(user: User): user is Modo {
  return 'role' in user && user.role === 'modo';
}

And use those functions like the following:
service.getCurrentUser().subscribe(user => {
  if (service.isAdminUser(user)) {
    // user now has type `Admin` in this block
    // you can safely use properties which only exist in the `Admin` type
  }
});


Thank you for your response! For example, how can I declare a variable of type Admin or Modo and then display its properties in the home template?
